# What is the optimal way to do server side paging in expressjs with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, performance, express

I'm currently doing a project with my own MEAN stack.

Now in a new project I'm creating I've got a collection that I'm paging with Express on serverside, returning the page size every time (e.g 10 results out of the total 2000) and the total rows found for the query the user preformed (e.g 193 for UserID 3).

Although this works fine, I'm afraid that this will create an enormous load on the server since a user can easily pull 50-60 pages a session with 10, 20, 50 or even 100 results each.

My question to you guys is: if I have say 1000 concurrent users paging every few seconds like this, will MongoDB be able to cope with this? If not, what might be my alternatives here?

Also is there anyway I can simulate such concurrent read tests on my app/MongoDB?

Please take in account that I must do server side paging because the app will be quite dynamic and information can change very often.

Comment: Did I answer your question? Or is there more you want to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're planning on only using a single webserver, you could cache the result set belonging to a certain page in memory. If you're planning on using multiple webservers, caching in-memory would lead to different result sets across servers, so in that case I'd recommend storing your cache either in MongoDB or in Redis.

A certain result set would be stored under a certain key in your cache. Your key would probably be composed of something like `entityName` + `filterOptions` + `offset` + `resultsLimit`. So for example you're loading `movies` with `title=titanic`, skipping the first 100, so `offset=100` and loading only 50 per page so `limit=50`, which would all be concatenated into a single key.

When a request comes in, you would first try to load the result set from the cache. If the result set is inside the cache, you'll return that to the client. If it's not in the cache, you'd query the database for the latest result set, put that in the cache and return it to the client.

Whether or not you could pull it off with 1000 concurrent users depends a lot on your hardware, the data you are loading, how you're loading it and the efficiency of your implementation. There's one way to find out, and that's testing.

Of course by using the asynchronous capabilities of Node.js you can achieve the best scalability, so every call that can be executed `async`, such as database calls, should definitely be executed asynchronously.

You could load test your application for free from your local computer using [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) or let it be tested using for example [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-web-app-performance-test/).